# What's wrong with this ALTER TABLE statement?`

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wrote a SQL statement to add some columns in my existing table `Company`, but it's causing an error.

This is my statement:

```
ALTER TABLE Company add(id3 int , id4 int, id5 int  , pjid int , ssid int , 
    searchkeyword1 nvarchar(max) ,searchkeyword2 nvarchar(max) ,
    searchkeyword3 nvarchar(max) ,searchkeyword4 nvarchar(max) );
```

Thanks ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omit the parenthesis:

```
ALTER TABLE Company add id3 int , id4 int, ... ;
```